# Returns the int unique

Tags: java, unique

I need to return the int unique SKU number for this item

```
public class SKU { 
    private static int pkey_next = 123018;
    public int getSKU() { // Returns the int unique SKU number for this item
        return pkey_next++;
    }
}
```

The SKU Class must have a `private static int pkey_next = 123018;` which will define the starting “primary key” identification number for items we have in our store. Since it starts at 123018, I should get `System.out.println(three.getSKU()); // 123020.`

I am getting 123018 right now.

Comment: and do you have a question?

Comment: And how should you get `123020` from `System.out.println(three.getSKU());`?

Comment: @SudhirOjha professor provides the test code

Comment: This method will return a different number each time it is called, rather than a different number for each instance.

Comment: And what is the output now?

Comment: Are there supposed to be two other instances before the one called `three`?

Comment: So, there are one and two before three

Comment: Please include all necessary information in your question. Don't make everyone try and guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to achieve atomicity while getting unique value. If yes then you can try something like the following

```
public class SKU {

    private static final AtomicInteger PKEY_NEXT = new AtomicInteger(123018);

    public int getSKU() { // Returns the int unique SKU number for this item
        //as you want increment of 2 so passing 2
        return PKEY_NEXT.addAndGet(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define the below Class**

```
public static class SKU {
    private static int pkey_next = 123018;

    public static int getSKU() {
        return ++pkey_next;
    }
}
```

**And use the following statment to fetch the method**

```
SKU.getSKU()
```

**In your case:**

```
System.out.println(SKU.getSKU());
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is what you are being asked for:

```
public class SKU { 
    private static int pkey_next = 123018;
    private int pkey;

    public SKU() {
        this.pkey = pkey_next++;
    }

    public int getSKU() { // Returns the int unique SKU number for this item
        return this.pkey;
    }
}
```

That is, actual give each instance its own unique `pkey` value, using the static field as a counter.

```
SKU one = new SKU();
SKU two = new SKU();
SKU three = new SKU();
System.out.println(three.getSKU()); // 123020
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing a post increment that is why getting the same value. You need to do pre-increment here i.e. increment before returning.
just change `return pkey_next++;` with `++pkey_next;`